# Jackson failed to write json tail to file

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson for writing log to file with 1 JSON per line. I have some Java DTO classes like

```
class A {
  private String a;
  private String b;
}
```

when I use Jackson `ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString(..)` most of the time it works.

```
{ "a": "<value_a1>", "b": "<value_b1>" }
{ "a": "<value_a2>", "b": "<value_b2>" }
```

However, sometimes the object is not finished and I got something like

```
{ "a": "<value_a1>"{ "a": "<value_a2>"
```

Anyone got some idea what is going on?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: close the file when you are done writing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was inconsistent using of encoding, i.e. the source was read by US_ASCII and write by UTF-8. Not related to JSON or Jackson.